# Distinct sequence takes less time to iterate compared to normal sequence

Tags: kotlin, sequence, execution-time

I've been reading about Kotlin sequences and saw that the `distinct` method is a `stateful intermediate` operation. I'm guessing it's *stateful* because obviously it needs to keep track of what elements it just saw to be able to remove duplicates; and also some code somewhere actually doing the duplicate check right ?

When I checked the time my code takes while not using `Sequence.distinct`, it took `50920 ms` to execute. But with the `distinct` operation it took even less time, `32548 ms`. This doesn't make sense to me since there should be extra code to check for duplicates.. What's the tradeoff here and what did I miss?

Here's the code i used to test, i just compose an alphabet sequence multiple times then call `distinct`:

```kotlin
val alphabet = sequenceOf( "", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")

fun iterate(digits: Int): Sequence<String> {
    var sequence = alphabet.asSequence()
    for (i in 1 until digits)
        sequence = iterate(sequence)
    return sequence.distinct()    // <--- this is where i add or remove the distinct
}

fun iterate(sequence: Sequence<String>) = sequence {
    sequence.forEach { c1 ->
        alphabet.forEach { c2 ->
            yield("$c1$c2")
        }
    }
}
```

While testing i've been doing :

```kotlin
iterate(7).forEach(::println)
```

So is it possible that the `println` takes more time than the duplicate check since `I/O` is always heavy ? I'm completely clueless and dumb-founded so any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Based on `cactustictacs` answer, I re-ran the code while generating 7 digit words so it's `11^7 == 19'487'171` total words being generated (I tried 8 digit words but I keep getting an `OutOfMemoryError` every time i used `distinct`, probably due to it keeping track of the elements it found so i can't really compare with more).

Here's the results (in ms) :

| Run # | With distinct | Without distinct |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 34015 | 47687 |
| 2 | 32454 | 48232 |
| 3 | 32842 | 47384 |
| 4 | 31037 | 47084 |
| 5 | 32224 | 48030 |
| 6 | 31660 | 47129 |
| 7 | 31678 | 48407 |
| 8 | 32123 | 51186 |
| 9 | 35136 | 48671 |
| 10 | 32245 | 47698 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's the same code, just with an extra `distinct()` operation at the end? Yeah that should make it take longer, since you're doing extra work that doesn't make it any more efficient.

But the actual execution time depends on system resources while the loop is running - if the system is busy, you'll see longer times. If you want to benchmark this stuff, you need to run it multiple times, and pick the most consistent numbers - maybe a median result (so you're ignoring any outliers)

You might need a much larger final sequence to see any notable *consistent* difference between running `distinct` or not though!

---

edit - I missed that you're printing every item in the sequence with some very large numbers, in that case yeah you're right, that's probably gonna be the bottleneck! Calling `distinct()` is going to cut down that work significantly here, because the way you're generating the sequence produces a lot of duplicates, especially as your iteration count gets larger:

```
fun main() {
    for (i in 1..5) {
        val results = iterate(i)
        val total = results.count()
        val distinct = results.distinct().count()
        println("$i) total: $total - difference: ${total - distinct}")
    }
}

1) total: 11 - difference: 0
2) total: 121 - difference: 10
3) total: 1331 - difference: 220
4) total: 14641 - difference: 3530
5) total: 161051 - difference: 49940
```

By 5 iterations you're stripping out almost a third of the results! That kind of work is generally fast, printing to output isn't so much. Try benchmarking each stage (the processing and the printing) and see what their averages are - because it's a sequence, you'll need to consume it to just do the "processing" step alone, running `count()` is a lightweight way to do that. Then you can compare that to the "processing + printing" version and see how much overhead the print adds

---

FYI (in case you're not doing this as a stress test) you can avoid the `distinct` call by just yielding each digit as part of each iteration:

```
// you don't really gain anything by having this as a sequence (it's slower too),
// but I'm keeping it the same for comparison's sake
val alphabet = (0..9).map(Int::toString).asSequence()

fun iterate(sequence: Sequence<String>) = sequence {
    // combo each item with each element in the sequence (if any)
    // this produces items at least two-digits long
    sequence.forEach { c1 ->
        alphabet.forEach { c2 ->
            yield("$c1$c2")
        }
    }
    // also yield all the single digits
    alphabet.forEach( { yield(it) })
}
```

That way the 1st iteration just produces single-digit items. The next extends each of those to create all the two-digit combos, and adds the single-digit items in too. The 3rd iteration extends each of those, creating all the 3-digit and 2-digit combinations, and adds the single-digit ones back in...

You're never producing duplicates, because each round is effectively just adding all the possible extensions of the current sequence. Using a blank character like you're doing complicates that, because each round adds extended versions of each item, but also non-extended duplicates of everything. It's easier to just turn all the *x*-length items into all the possible *x+1*-length items, then throw all the single-digit items back in (since the ones in the previous sequence got extended to two digits)

I hope that's not too confusing, I feel like it's an overcomplicated explanation. Also this way doesn't yield an empty string as part of the sequence (the combo of `"" + "" + ""...`) - if you need that you could do `return sequence.plus("")` or something

I get a 2-3x speed increase with this for 5 iterations - it's not just the `distinct` call, you're avoiding doing duplicate work in the first place, and with more iterations that inefficiency can really add up! Especially for `sequence`s, which are memory-efficient and let you stop earlier, but run a lot slower than `iterable`s

Comment: Ok let me try that, I'll run it 10 times and average out the results with and without the `distinct`

Comment: @Lorenzo oh ok, I missed the size of the data set and how much the ``distinct`` call was removing - I've updated the answer with a bit more info! Hope it helps

Comment: That pretty much explains everything nicely, Thanks a lot for the nice edit! And yeah it's pretty much that blank char (in the sequence) that makes me generate a lot of duplicates and eventually lead to many more `println` (hence `I/O` calls), but I guess i'll re-think the whole generation part for my own project to try and avoid them as much as possible then. Thanks a lot again!